# Change opacity of fill area in combo chart (Google charts)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I was working on the combo chart (bar + scatter chart) of Google charts. I was not able to change the opacity of the data point and the fill area inside the bars. There was not much information provided in the documentation and I tried to change opacity using methods mentioned for other charts but nothing seemed to work.

Here is the link to the chart I was trying to work on- [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ry4nde8/72/)

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var sett = 'fill-color: #76A7FA; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke-color: #76A7FA; stroke-width: 1;';
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Average', {
        role: 'style'
      }],
      ['2004/05', 450, 614.6, sett],
      ['2005/06', 288, 682, sett],
      ['2006/07', 397, 623, sett],
      ['2007/08', 215, 609.4, sett],
      ['2008/09', 366, 569.6, sett],
      ['2009/05', 450, 614.6, sett],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Cups'
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      legend: 'none',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      pointShape: {
        type: 'triangle',
        rotation: 180
      },
      pointSize: 7,
      series: {
        0: {
          type: 'bars',
          areaOpacity: 0.3
        },
        1: {
          type: 'scatter',
          opacity: 0.5,
          color: 'blue'
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a `'style'` column role to change the opacity,
which it appears you have

however, the style role must follow each series column to which you want to apply the style

so to make the columns opaque, add the style following the second column,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var sett = 'fill-color: #76A7FA; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke-color: #76A7FA; stroke-width: 1;';
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', {role: 'style'}, 'Average', {role: 'style'}],
    ['2004/05', 450, sett, 614.6, sett],
    ['2005/06', 288, sett, 682, sett],
    ['2006/07', 397, sett, 623, sett],
    ['2007/08', 215, sett, 609.4, sett],
    ['2008/09', 366, sett, 569.6, sett],
    ['2009/05', 450, sett, 614.6, sett],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Cups'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Month'
    },
    legend: 'none',
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    pointShape: {
      type: 'triangle',
      rotation: 180
    },
    pointSize: 7,
    series: {
      0: {
        type: 'bars',
        areaOpacity: 0.3
      },
      1: {
        type: 'scatter',
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: 'blue'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and found an easier way to control the opacity of bar charts in Google Charts.

I found an easy way of doing this and want to contribute my answer for those who come next!

We can control the opacity of individual series (including bars) by using `dataOpacity`:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Average'],
    ['2004/05', 450, 614.6],
    ['2005/06', 288, 682],
    ['2006/07', 397, 623],
    ['2007/08', 215, 609.4],
    ['2008/09', 366, 569.6],
    ['2009/05', 450, 614.6],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Cups'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Month'
    },
    legend: 'none',
    pointShape: {
      type: 'triangle',
      rotation: 180
    },
    pointSize: 7,
    series: {
      0: {
        type: 'bars',
        dataOpacity: 0.3
      },
      1: {
        type: 'scatter',
        color: 'blue',
        dataOpacity: 0.6
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: You are my hero of the week. I cannot understand that for Google, setting visual styles in the dataset is common practise. I wanted to change the Stroke-color and stroke-width too for which I tried dataStrokeColor and dataStrokeWidth (would've been an easy one) but that didn't work. Any other suggestions? Where did you find out about dataOpactity?

Comment: Thank you! I agree that combining style with actual data is confusing. I wonder what their reasoning was?

I found dataOpacity in the documentation for Combo Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart.

Regarding stroke-color and stroke-width: I looked around right now and could only find them being set using the "setting visual styles in the data" way, like on this page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#column-styles